# fsck_apfs not working from terminal in single user mode

Tags: macos, catalina, fsck, apfs

I am trying to fix errors on my `MacIntosh HD Data` volume.

I have tried to fix using Disk Utility from normal mode and from recovery mode. Same problem. DI hangs at a certain point and that's it.

I boot into single user mode.

Using `df -h` I see that the `MacIntosh HD Data` volume is `/dev/disk2s1`.

I try to type:

```
fsck_apfs -y /dev/disk2s1
```

and I get this:

> error: device is unreadable because you are in single user mode.

I try the same command from normal boot and I get

> error: container /dev/rdisk1 is mounted with write access.

I have done this thousands of times before, from single user mode. This is some Catalina crap.

How do I do that now on Catalina?

Comment: Is the disk encrypted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Correction

Apple's official word is that the traditional single-user mode which one enters by booting whilst holding ⌘S is deprecated on macOS Mojave (10.14) and later. This is due to the presence of the Apple T2 security chip in Macs which initially went to market with Mojave or later.

From [Mac startup key combinations](https://support.apple.com/HT201255):

> - **Command-S:** Start up in [single-user mode](https://support.apple.com/HT201573). Disabled in [macOS Mojave or later](https://support.apple.com/HT201260), or when using a [firmware password](https://support.apple.com/HT204455).

And from the small print on the linked "single-user mode" page, [Start up your Mac in single-user mode or verbose mode](https://support.apple.com/HT201573):

> These steps replace the Command-S method, which doesn't work with the recommended settings on [current Mac computers](https://support.apple.com/HT208862).

The linked page "current Mac computers" refers to those which have a T2 chip.

Despite the claim that the traditional single-user mode is outright disabled on Mojave and later, you can still boot into it using ⌘S on devices which *don't* have a T2 chip, even if you attempt to do so on a system running Mojave or later. However, this single-user mode will require access to the data and VM volumes of the APFS container that contains the OS, and you will find that you are unable to unmount these volumes in order to run `fsck_apfs -y` on that container. This is because `umount` will refuse to unmount the volumes due to them being actively used, and you cannot forcibly unmount them using `diskutil` since the DiskManagement framework required by `diskutil` is not loaded/present in this mode — and even if this were possible in some other way, it is unadvisable to forcibly unmount elements of a filesystem that you are trying to repair!

Having said that, macOS still technically has a single-user mode in Mojave and later: the Terminal in macOS Recovery. After actually trying to use `fsck_apfs -y` in this environment, it turns out that it is possible, but you will first need to unmount any mounted APFS volumes belonging to the APFS container that contains the OS; macOS Recovery will automatically mount the data and VM volumes by default. Because macOS Recovery isn't as stripped down as the traditional single-user mode, you can do this simply with e.g. `diskutil unmountDisk disk2`. You can use `mount` and `diskutil apfs list` to determine the device nodes.

---

## Original answer

This isn't a Catalina thing, but an APFS thing. You cannot perform reparatory actions on an APFS container (or any of its volumes, since this requires acting on the container) when that container is mounted. If any volume in that container is mounted, then the container itself is necessarily also mounted.

<s>As such, you cannot use `fsck_apfs -y` on the APFS partition that you have booted from, whether that's in a regular environment, in single-user mode, in recovery mode, or however else.</s> You can still run `fsck_apfs -nl` when booted normally to inspect the APFS partition for errors, but this will not repair any such errors.

To run `fsck_apfs -y` on your Catalina APFS partition, you <s>must access</s> *could also try accessing* the disk another way, such as:

- booting into Catalina Internet Recovery *(which also requires you to unmount the automatically mounted volumes)*.
- booting from a Catalina USB installer.
- booting your Mac in Target Disk Mode and connecting it to a secondary Mac running Catalina, then running `fsck_apfs` from the secondary Mac on the affected disk.
- physically removing the disk from your Mac and connecting it to a secondary Mac running Catalina, then running `fsck_apfs` from the secondary Mac on the affected disk.

Since new, significant APFS features were introduced in Catalina ("volume groups" in particular), avoid using any `fsck_apfs` belonging to an older macOS version, particularly if you are trying to repair incorrectly allocated disk space. `fsck_apfs(8)` states for the `-o` option:

> **`-o`** — Repair overallocations; please do not run an older `fsck_apfs` on newer systems with this option.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Apple do these changes and have zero documentation about it. I am not 100% sure right now but I think I tried that booting from internet recovery. Anyway, I was forced to restore the disk from time machine because I was unable to repair  the disk, a task that was easily done before Catalina, by using fsck from single user mode. What annoys me the hell out of Apple is the inability to create an error message that makes sense and explains, like "cannot run fsck from single user mode, run it from internet recovery mode."

Comment: "Apple do these changes and have zero documentation about it." — Indeed, it is a nuisance.

Comment: "What annoys me the hell out of Apple is the inability to create an error message that makes sense and explains [...]" — These are relatively low-level tools, so even I wouldn't expect that from them. Rather, you're expected to know what you're doing and identify roadblocks by yourself. In this particular case, the problem isn't really due to you being in single-user mode, so there's quite simply no way for the system to determine that's the cause in order to report it to you. For example, you could run `fsck_apfs` just fine in single-user mode on a disk that isn't the one you booted from.

Comment: "I think I tried that booting from internet recovery." — I shall double-check this, since I can't imagine any reason why `fsck_apfs` would complain in Internet Recovery.

Comment: @SpaceDog I finally got round to trying this in Internet Recovery, and it is possible — you just need to unmount the auto-mounted volumes first. For that reason, it's actually also possible in Recovery booted from disk, since that's booted entirely in RAM. See my edited answer for details.

Comment: Thanks. Just to confirm. So in my case, with an old iMac and Mojave, I have to boot into recovery mode, `diskutil unmountDisk disk2` and then `fsck_apfs -fy`, right?

Comment: @SpaceDog Provided that `disk2` is the mounted APFS container, then yes. Also, `fsck_apfs` has no `-f` option

Comment: Hi again. Catalina is a disgrace. Today I was forced to power shutdown my Mac two times. After doing something like that I generally run `fsck_apfs` to check the disk before using the computer again. I did what you said: boot into recovery mode, unmounted the disks and run `fsck_apfs -y` on them. Saw two errors like `error: Cross Check : Mismatch between extentref entry reference count (0) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (2) for extent (0x1b32437 + 1)` but `fsck` was unable to fix them. FSCK is not good as it was before. Thanks.

Comment: @SpaceDog, again, this is not Catalina specifically, but due to the macOS APFS tools not being very fleshed out (here, `fsck_apfs`; it doesn't recover from most errors in my experience, either). It has been like this since High Sierra. Honestly, Apple's forced rollout of APFS is ridiculous, given that the specification is *still* in flux.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what else has been said, when working with an encrypted volume, you'd have to unlock the volume without mounting it.

Find the drive / volume:

```
# diskutil apfs list
...
      Volume diskXsY
      FileVault:    Yes (Locked)
...
```

Unlock without mounting:

```
# diskutil apfs unlockVolume /dev/diskXsY -nomount
...
Unlocked but did not mount APFS Volume
```

Verify that unlocking succeeded for all volumes:

```
# diskutil apfs list
...
      Volume diskXsY
      FileVault:    Yes (Unlocked)
...
```